# Web API for pulling text from article url?

Tags: api, screen-scraping, readability

I like the products provided by Read it Later, Instapaper, Readability, etc. where they strip out the core of an article and display it back to you formatted nicely: just text and images from the article. I am looking for a good API to do this.

I discovered by accident that instapaper can do this for me:

http://www.instapaper.com/text?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.co.uk%2Fnews%2F14185334

However, I obviously cannot rely on this, as it isn't documented on their API.

Does anyone know of an online API that I can use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/text/ , pretty sure I've seen other services as well